# curl equivalent to python POST requests to call jenkins api

Tags: python-3.x, jenkins, curl, python-requests, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to call jenkins api to build a job using curl command which perfectly fine. Here is my curl command:

```
curl -X POST https://myjenkinshost/job/myorg/job/10042/job/myproject/job/10042_myansiblejob/build --user admuser:my-token --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name": "ENVIRONNEMENT", "value": "developpement"},{"name": "REFERENCE_GIT_INVENTAIRE", "value": "develop"},{"name": "REFERENCE_GIT_PLAYBOOK", "value": "develop"},{"name": "VAULT", "value": "mysecretpassword"},{"name": "EXTRA_VARS", "value": "myhosts: TARGET"}]}'
```

But when I try this with python, it always shows HTTP 400 :

Error:

> Reason: HTTP ERROR 400.  Problem accessing /job/10042/job/myproject/job/10042_myansiblejob/build. Nothing is submitted

Here is my python code which is very simple, could be a very small issue.

```
import requests
import json


basicAuthCredentials = ('admuser', 'my-token') 
jenkins_headers={'Content-type':'application/json', 'Accept':'application/json'}

ansible_vault_password="mysecretpassword"
JENKINS_URL="https://myjenkinshost/job/myorg/job/10042/job/myproject/job/10042_myansiblejob/build"

ENVIRONNEMENT="developpement"
GIT_BRANCH="develop"
ANSIBLE_EXTRA_VARS_VARNAME="myhosts: TARGET"

json_payload='{"parameter": [{"name": "ENVIRONNEMENT", "value": "'+ENVIRONNEMENT+'"'+ \
                '},{"name": "REFERENCE_GIT_INVENTAIRE", "value": "'+GIT_BRANCH+'"'+ \
                '},{"name": "REFERENCE_GIT_PLAYBOOK", "value": "'+GIT_BRANCH+'"'+ \
                '},{"name": "VAULT", "value": "'+ansible_vault_password+'"'+ \
                '},{"name": "EXTRA_VARS", "value": "'+ANSIBLE_EXTRA_VARS_VARNAME+'"}]}'

json_data=json.dumps(json_payload)

response_jenkins = requests.post(JENKINS_URL, headers=jenkins_headers,                
    data=json_data, auth=basicAuthCredentials)

print(response_jenkins.text)
```

Reference: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/remote-access-api/

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From curl command you are doing [--data-urlencode](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-urlencode), which is sending `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

From your python you are passing `Content-type':'application/json`.

Comment: I had tried that before as well, it did not work. As you said I tried now as well, same results.